Powershell: How to add new values to an array
I have an Netapp .csv containing volume names, size, etc. and I'm importing this into an Powershell array $volumes.
I'm filtering the stuff I need:
$volumes | select Name,"Storage VM",Capacity

However, the "Capacity" is in Byte and I'd like to display in GB. I know how to convert, but I don't know how to add the converted item into the existing array:
foreach ($vol in $volumes) { $volsizeGB = $vol.Capacity/1GB }

How do I add this "$volsizeGB" to the $volumes?
Thanks

So really you want to modify objects in an array, not add new objects.

If you want to update the property value of each Capacity property:
foreach ($vol in $volumes) { $vol.Capacity = $vol.Capacity / 1GB }

If you want to add a new property with the formatted capacity it's better to use Select-Object with a calculated property:
$volumes | Select-Object @(
    'Name'
    'Storage VM'
    'Capacity'
    @{ N='FormattedCapacity'; E={ $_.Capacity / 1GB }})


as a side note, if you have MANY properties in $volumes you can use $volumes | Select-Object -Property *, @{Name = 'FormattedCapacity'; Expression = { $_.Capacity / 1GB } }.
